# How can I stop pgadmin 4 process?

Tags: pgadmin

How can I stop pgadmin 4 process?
I ran pgadmin 4 next method:

`python3 /usr/local/pgAdmin4.py`

My idea using Ctrl-c.

Comment: This is a good question. I'm killing with kill -9 $PID, but i dont know if this is correct way. I've tried with -SIGINT, but not close always

Answer (score 39):

If you are using pgAdmin 4 on mac OS or Ubuntu, you can use system tool bar (at the top of the screen) icon for this. After you start pgAdmin server the icon with elephant head should appear. If you click it you will have an option `Shut down server`.

Comment: Just to clarify: pressing the button asks you if you're sure you want to shut down the server but it just means the admin tool. Gets me every time.

Comment: What are you talking about? Pgadmin4 is a background daemon process accessed via a web browser. There is no Gnome application icon to represent the running process...

Comment: yes it is :), I used it very often and looks like other people are also found this icon

Comment: did not notice there is a shutdown server button in that menu after clicking the pgadmin elephant, my bad! :)

Answer (score 7):

You can shut down the server[image] from the top menu as shown.

Just click the Shutdown server and it will work.

Comment: The Windows version does not seem to have that option implemented...

Comment: Sorry, I dont use windows and am not familiar with what's being offered there.